# ¿Por qué me aparece el error "Failed to execute script" con ejecutable creado con pyinstaller?

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica, pyinstaller, kivy, exe

La unica librería que estoy usando es kivy para una app sencilla, hice el ejecutable con el siguiente comando:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile --icon='C:\Users\<User>\Desktop\pasos\Lambda.ico' .\Lambda.py>
```

Muestra un error:

[image: 1]

No sé a que se deba si previamente había hecho una prueba pero solo con *matplotlib* y si mostraba la gráfica, alguien que me explique que hice mal, o si es problema de las versiones:

> ```
> (Python 3.11.7)
> (pyinstaller               6.3.0),
> (Kivy                      2.2.1),
> (kivy-deps.angle           0.3.3),
> (kivy-deps.glew            0.3.1),
> (kivy-deps.gstreamer       0.3.3),
> (kivy-deps.sdl2            0.6.0),
> (Kivy-Garden               0.1.5)
> ```

Comment: Hola, agrega siempre código y la traza de los errores como texto, no como imágenes, Dicho esto, prueba a generar el ejecutable con  `pyinstaller --debug --onefile --icon='C:\Users\<User>\Desktop\pasos\Lambda.ico' .\Lambda.py`, esto deberia abrir una instancia de la terminal cuando ejecutas el exe y mostrar información de depuración en ella. Agrega lo que te muestre a la pregunta a ver si aclara algo.

Comment: Hola gracias por las sugerencias, pero ya encontré donde se origina el error, no es en el codigo, es en la opccion de '--noconsole', la quité esa opcion y funciona pero lo que yo quiero es que no aparezca, alguna manera de arreglarlo?

Comment: Que no aparezca cuando no usas el argumento `--noconsole`/`--windowed` indica que hay algo en tu código (o en las librerías que usas) que necesita de una instancia de la terminal para funcionar, seguramente algo que hace uso de la salida/entrada estándar (como `input`/`print`/`sys.stdout`, etc). Viendo la captura de la ventana con la traza parcial del error que muestras es posible que sea [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) el causante. Mira la terminal cuando ejecutas la app a ver si te da alguna pista.